# Check schedule overlap using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I Have a table like below

```
SL  Classroom  Weekday  StartTime  EndTime
--  ---------  -------  ---------  --------  
1   ADMN-100   Friday   01:00:00   02:00:00
2   ADMN-100   Friday   02:00:00   03:00:00
3   ADMN-100   Monday   01:00:00   02:00:00
4   LAB-501    Monday   01:00:00   02:00:00
```

Using LINQ, how can I check if a time overlap is occurring?

I failed doing below,

```
bool check = true;
check = db.Classrooms.Any(x => x.Classroom.Equals(roomNo)
                                   && x.Weekday.Equals(weekDay)
                                   && x.StartTime < startsAt
                                   && x.EndTime > startsAt);
```

Comment: You're kind of missing some detail here, but do you have the sign flipped?  Shouldn't you be checking is the start time is *earlier* than startsAt?

Comment: I think should be `startsAt  > x.StartTime && x.EndTime > startsAt`

Comment: Are StartTime/EndTime string objects or some other object type?  If they are DateTime objects, what are their year/month/day components?

Comment: The way to check for overlap is `start1 < end2 && start2 < end1`

Comment: Casey, Arturo Menchaca and  juharr, you guys are right. Changed the question as well as in my code. But not solved yet.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter, Time properties are TimeSpan type and in Data Annotation, [DataType(DataType.Time)] is used. So, there is no other components except time.

Comment: If that hasn't fixed it then you need to post more of the code because this part doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to get compare a single datetime range again db Classroom to prevent overlap inserts? Or every classrom to each other to make sure not overlap are on db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I wanted to do something like this, because I had to iterate through each row to find the combination,

```
foreach (var val in DataSource)
        {
            if (roomNo.Equals(val.Classroom))
            {
                if (weekDay.Equals(val.ClassRoomWeekDay))
                {
                    if (startsAt>= val.StartTime && startsAt< val.EndTime )
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost correct, but change `x.StartTime < startsAt` to `x.StartTime < endsAt`.  `Schedule` class is below for completeness.

```
class Schedule
{
    public string Classroom { get; set; }
    public string Weekday { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }

    public bool OverlapsWith(Schedule schedule)
    {
        return schedule.StartTime < EndTime && 
               schedule.EndTime > StartTime && 
               schedule.Weekday == Weekday && 
               schedule.Classroom == Classroom;
    }
}
```

A quick note - use `TimeSpan` so that a `DateTime` object will not mess up you logic if the month, year, or day is off.  [What you really want is a time of day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689027/whats-best-practice-to-represent-a-time-object-in-c), and `TimeSpan` offers "Hours", "Minutes" and "Seconds" which is what you really want.  The comparisons will work with `TimeSpan` objects.  I'm not sure how this will work with EF, though.

If you need a string to `TimeSpan` conversion, try [`TimeSpan.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx).  It should work for the format that you presented in your question.

The `OverlapsWith` method probably won't be inside of `Schedule`, but it's there just to show you that your code is basically the same.

Comment: The problem with `TimeSpan` is that it gives an elapsed time, not a time of day.

Comment: "Elapsed time since the day started" is the same thing as the "time of day".  Interpreting a `TimeSpan` this way is the closest way of doing this that I know of.  Check out the [link in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689027/whats-best-practice-to-represent-a-time-object-in-c) for another SO post on the topic.

Comment: As a note, this would force the user to use 24 hour time. Just make sure you remember to do conversions if needed. However, I think this is the route to take. Upvoting.

Comment: Yes my Class properties are declared like you have shown.

Comment: @Tareq are you still having problems?  Which case is not working?  In your example of 4 schedules, I don't see any overlaps.  Is there more data that you are testing?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter, it works partially. Like, considering Classroom = ADMN-100, Weekday = Friday , if I enter 1:30 then it works fine and shows time is overlapped, which is true for SL - 1. But, considering same Classroom and Weekday if I enter 2:30, then it supposed to say time overlapped because SL-2 has the schedule, but it does not work.

Comment: If different classrooms are used at the same time, there is no overlap.  The same classroom needs to be used on the same day at the same time for there to be an overlap, correct?  It seems you are expecting to see an overlap if two different classrooms are used at the same time.  If you want this, remove `x.Classroom.Equals(roomNo)` from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using `Datetime.Compare()` method? Like so:

```
.Any(
Datetime.Compare(x.StartTime, startsAt)>0 
&&
Datetime.Compare(x.EndTime, startsAt)<0
)
```

Comment: I don't think `DateTime.Compare` will translate to SQL in EF.  But really it's not any different from just using the operators instead.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are not capturing all the possible overlap cases. This is what you want.

```
check = classes.Any(x=>x.Classroom.Equals(roonNo)
                       && x.Weekday.Equals(weekDay)
                       && x.StartTime <= endsAt
                       && x.EndTime >= startsAt);
```

Comment: If you don't have an `endsAt` time, you can just use `startsAt` in both places and the result is the same. Although this then degrades to Matt Rowlands answer.

Answer (score 0):

To select elements with matching results

```
      var v=  c.ones.Select(x=>x).Where(x =>  x.weekday.Equals("mon")
                               && x.starttime == TimeSpan.Parse("08:00")
                               && x.endtime == TimeSpan.Parse("09:00"));
```

To find out if overlapping exist

```
     IQueryable<bool> v=  c.ones.Select(x =>  x.weekday.Equals("mon")
                               && x.starttime == TimeSpan.Parse("08:00")
                               && x.endtime == TimeSpan.Parse("09:00"));
```