# Kendo Grid with EditorTemplate TimeSpan

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, timepicker

I have a Kendo Grid that has a EditorTemplate with a timepicker in it.  The timepicker works great and the Time displays on the grid fine, but when I try to save it is erroring saying the value isn't correct for the object.  Below is my code. When I hit save it tells errors saying "The value '2/24/2014 07:00:00 AM' is not valid for Brief.  The time is the time I selected from the timepicker.  How do I just send the Time only without the date, or what is the best option to save the Time only to the database?

ViewModel (Partly):

```
[UIHint("_TimePicker")]
public TimeSpan? Brief { get; set; }

[UIHint("_TimePicker")]
public TimeSpan? KickOff { get; set; }

[UIHint("_TimePicker")]
public TimeSpan? Debrief { get; set; }
```

Grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Optic_Freedom.Areas.Scheduling.Models.ExerciseBreakdownViewModel>()
        .Name(string.Format("Grid"))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Personnel.Name).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.NumberOfTeams).Width(80);
            columns.Bound(p => p.TeamMembers).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Vehicles).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Brief).Format("{0:HH:mm}").EditorTemplateName("_TimePicker1").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.KickOff).Format("{0:HH:mm}").EditorTemplateName("_TimePicker2").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Debrief).Format("{0:HH:mm}").EditorTemplateName("_TimePicker3").Width(100);
        })
```

EditorTemplate:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model TimeSpan?

@(Html.Kendo().TimePickerFor(m=>m)
      .Value(@Model.GetValueOrDefault())
      .Min("06:00")
      .Max("22:00")
      .Format("{0:HH:mm}"))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to store it in a DateTime structure and parse the time out of it. TimeSpan is for storing a length of time (e.g. 35 mins), rather than a specific time of day (11:30 EST).
Jon Skeet discusses his Noda Time library in [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11598697) which may help.

Comment: Actually can't change it to a datetime.  When I do that, the timepicker errors stating that the date isn't correct.