# Sort a list by a string property, Where the string is of a Nullable decimal

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a list that contains an object. The object has a string property called `AppointmentTime`. This is used in my view, Arguably this may be better as a DateTime property using stringFormat on the binding.

So my objects may have an AppointmentTime that looks Something like this:

```
Object1.AppointmentTime = "12.41"
Object2.AppointmentTime = "13.49"
Object3.AppointmentTime = ""
Object4.AppointmentTime = "9.43"
```

I now want to sort this list by this property, with the empty strings at the bottom of the list

So far I have tried:

```
ListofObjects.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.AppointmentTime);
```

but without luck... Any ideas?

**EDIT - My Solution**

As someone in the comment very kindly pointed out. Using the OrderBy creates a new list and does not order the original list. Silly Microsoft, should warn you that you have not set the new list equal to anything. My Final Solution was:

```
diaryEntries = new ObservableCollection<DiaryEntryViewModel>(diaryEntries.OrderBy(x => x.AppointmentTime).OrderBy(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AppointmentTime)));
```

Although I feel the longterm solution is to change this property to a DateTime as suggested

Comment: I think you answered your question in the second sentence, better to use a `DateTime` (or `DateTime?`) data type :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change my `AppointmentTime` to a `DateTime` and then the `OrderBy` would be a piece of cake:

```
ListofObjects = ListofObjects.OrderBy(x => x.AppointmentTime).ToList();
```

As for the `View` you refer to, you can later format the string representation of your `DateTime` as you want. This way you will have achieve the easiest way to order your data and then you will have the required format in your view.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is passing `""` to `Convert.ToDecimal`: you would trigger an exception. You could work around this issue by adding an explicit check, like this:

```
ListofObjects.OrderBy(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AppointmentTime) ? null : (decimal?)Convert.ToDecimal(x.AppointmentTime));
```

However, the best approach would be using a built-in type to represent the time. For example, [a nullable `TimeSpan?` could be used to represent the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2037375/335858) of an appointment.