# How to setup specific range of time (example from 07:00 to 12:00) regardless of the date

Tags: c#, api

I'm trying to create class where *Physician.cs* have a *ICollection Appointmets* property with DateTime inside of it but I'm trying to create *Workday* class where Physician can say from when he start to when he finishes his workday (ex. Monday from 07:00 to 13:00 regardless of the date).

Do I need to declare DateTime as datatype to the property of *Start* and *Finish* in *Workday* class?

**Physician.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Med_App_API.Models
{
    public class Physician
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Appointments> Appointments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Appointment.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Med_App_API.Models
{
    public class Appointments
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }
        public int PhysicianId { get; set; }
        public Physician Physician { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeofAppointment { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfAppointment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Workday.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Med_App_API.Models
{
    public class Workday
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PhysicianId { get; set; }
        public Physician Physician { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime Finish { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime` if you don't want the date portion. You'll need to add guards/validation to the properties to ensure the values are in the appropriate range (0 - 24 hours, or whatever).

Comment: Or you can use the `LocalTime` struct in the NodaTime library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I represent a time only value in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037283/how-do-i-represent-a-time-only-value-in-net)

Comment: *>Do I need to declare DateTime as datatype to the property of Start and Finish in Workday class?* No, you don't. You might for example use a `TimeSpan` or a `byte` or `int` that represents the hour part of the weekday.

Comment: Ok but when lets say patient wants to create an appointment on some date during the time physician works ```DateTime``` is enough as property @HereticMonkey?

Comment: If you have a date and a time on that date, `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset` if you need to deal with time zones) is an appropriate type to use, sure. You should really just look at [the documentation for DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) and the associated topics. Keeping track of events occurring in time is a huge topic, and many, many, people have  written papers and developed millions of lines of codes devoted to the subject.

Comment: "Easy :             DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan time = date - date.Date;