# What Benefits Does TimeOnly Have Over TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, types, .net-6.0, timespan

`TimeOnly` was one of the new types introduced with .Net 6 along with `DateOnly`. I understand the great need for the `DateOnly` type as there are many instances you would want to store a date without a related time but no data type that did so.

However, in regards to time, `TimeSpan` already exists and is capable of representing times. `Timespan` very similar to `TimeOnly` except, `TimeOnly` seems to have a few properties missed.

Is there any great benefit offered from using `TimeOnly` instead of `TimeSpan` apart from saving a bit a memory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I represent a time only value in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037283/how-do-i-represent-a-time-only-value-in-net)

Comment: This concern of the question is the benefits of ```TimeOnly``` vs ```TimeSpan``` not just how to represent Time.

Comment: Note that a difference between TimeOnly is always positive and can be confusing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039686/timespan-calculation-is-different-between-timeonly-and-datetime#comment129031324_73039686

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim true - I did mention in my answer, that `TimeSpan` has a range of approx +/- 29,000 years and that `TimeOnly` can only represent times on a 24hr clock.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the benefits I can see from using `TimeOnly` instead of `TimeSpan` is in having appropriate data types to represent periods of time vs times of the day.

`TimeOnly` is better suited for times of day and `TimeSpan` is better suited for representing durations/periods of time. It also has methods that correctly handle additions/subtractions to times that cross over midnight unlike `TimeSpan`

e.g. 23:00 + 2hrs would equal 01:00 (with `TimeOnly`).

`TimeOnly` only allows you to modify it in ways that will produce a valid time of day but `TimeSpan` allows modifications that could result in a value that is out of range.

`TimeSpan` can represent a larger range of time periods (including negative periods of time), it has a range of  about +/- 29,000 years whereas `TimeOnly`can only represent 00:00:00.0000000 to 23:59:59.9999999.

The following blog post provides more info on the `TimeOnly` type (as well as `DateOnly`): https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/

Comment: How is a lot of space saved if they're both represented internally a long?

Comment: @Robear you're right, they are both just 8 bytes.